# How to run a jquery event when it's clicked in this particular case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#hideButton').click(function (e) {
    var key = $(e.relatedTarget).data('applicationkey');
    viewModel.previewApplicationKey(key);
});
```

I wanted to make it run when I click the item with id = hideButton.
I wanted to add relatedTarget.data('applicationkey') to a viewModel called
previewApplication.

How can I correct this code?

EDIT: okay sorry for the lack of explanation. Here is what's going on.

```
<i id="hideCross" class="fa fa-2x fa-times" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }" data-applicationkey="abc9rbwys"></i>
```

This icon with id = hideCross has data-applicationkey="abc9rbwys" as you see.

```
$('#hideCross').click(function (e) {
    var key = $(e.relatedTarget).data('applicationkey');
    viewModel.previewApplicationKey(key);
});
```

So this shoud add "abc9rbwys" to my previewApplicationKey viewModel in theory.
Do you see any error? I am not getting an error message, but it just doesnt add the key to the viewModel.

Comment: in what way does your code fail? does the code run when you click the aforementioned item?

Comment: Whats the error? We understood what you have done and your code, but what and where is the error?

Comment: Probably because [`relatedTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/) is only useful for `mouseout` / `mouseover` events. What element were you expecting from a `click` event?

Comment: I don't understand why Knockout can't handle the click event (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html, "Note 1: Passing a “current item” as a parameter to your handler function").  You are using jQuery to modify a Knockout ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you just want to read the attribute of the tag was clicked, you should be able to do this simply using `$(this)` since you are attaching event handler to the same element that has this attribute:

```
$('#hideCross').click(function (e) {
    var key = $(this).data('applicationkey');
    viewModel.previewApplicationKey(key);
});
```

**UPDATE:** as @Janar mentioned, you are probably using same ids for your elements, which is not correct. Try using some [other jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to attach event handlers to your elements, like:

```js
var viewModel = [];

$('i[data-applicationkey]').click(function (e) {
    var key = $(this).data('applicationkey');
    viewModel.push(key); 
    console.log(viewModel);
});
```

```css
i {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="fa fa-2x fa-times" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }" data-applicationkey="abc9rbwys">Click me to add applicationkey</i>

<br/>

<i class="fa fa-2x fa-times" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }" data-applicationkey="asdfasfasfd">Click me to add applicationkey</i>

<br/>

<i class="fa fa-2x fa-times" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }" data-applicationkey="1345dfsgsdg">Click me to add applicationkey</i>
```

Comment: Wait sorry. Actually it still doesnt add the item to the viewModel when I click it. There are more than one items. When I click the first one, it works fine. But when I try to click a different item, the applicationKey remains the same,

Comment: @user7677413 are you using same ids as Janar mentioned? Can you create an example with more items that will illustrate your issue? See update, maybe it will help you. Btw, what framework are you using? Maybe there is a better way of event handling.